# How to loop a jar file requiring arguments endlessly with a batch file?

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, jar

By now I'm pretty good with running my Java code in Eclipse. But for my next project, I'll need to loop the program as much as possible. I think, the best way to do this would be a looping batch file, which I have no idea of how to write it.

So there is this *example.jar* file, containing several different classes, which I cannot alter in any way. The only thing I can do is changing the Manifest through the cfm console command.

In eclipse I could set the main to *exampleMain.class* and set the arguments to *-t X SomeActuallyIrrelevantName package.className package.className2*, with X being a number. I actually have no idea what *-t* does.

Whenever i try to call the *example.jar* through the command line (*java -jar example.jar*) it says, that the main class couldn't be loaded or found. I tried altering the main class in the manifest (from *exampleMain* to *exampleMain.class* to *example.exampleMain* and *example.exampleMain.class*), but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: You will need to post the script that you've tried so far. And you should also post the internal structure of your jar file. Does your example.jar have any dependencies on any other jars? I assume you wish to call several classes in sequence from this single jar via the batch file? Once I know all of the above, then I can provide a solution for you.

Comment: java -cp example.jar package.NameOfClassThatYouWantToRun

Comment: @ManoDestra: _example.jar_ contains the framework to a board game for which _package.className_ and _package.className2_ are my self programmed players, and _X_ is the time limit for each turn. I want to change the values for each player by its intialization through the _exampleMain.class_, but since I cannot change the _exampleMain.class_ to run infinitely (or rather just several thousand times), i want to loop it in a batch file. Ther are no other jar files, except _example.jar_, which only contains the visualization of the game and alternate calling of the two players.

Comment: @Borut Hadžialić this only leads to the same result: main class could not be found or loaded.

Comment: @ManoDestra since i don't know how to write a .bat file, i tried starting it through the console with following commands:
`jar cfm example.jar newManifest.txt` to change the manifest inside the jar, pointing to the _exampleMain.class_ (This worked, I could see the changes in eclipse)
then I tried running i with `java -jar example.jar` which returned the error message as well as `java -jar example.jar "-t" "X" "rrelevantName" "package.className" "package.className2"` and the same again without the " - same result.

Comment: Don't run the jar as a jar. In other words, don't use -jar when you call it. Just run the classes you wish to run, as @BorutHadžialić has suggested above. For example, if your jar is called game.jar and your class is game.Game1, then use java -cp game.jar game.Game1 to call the Game1 class. If your game has any other dependencies, you'll have to add them to the classpath also, along with your jar after the -cp parameter, delimited by ;.

Comment: @ManoDestra I'm sorry if I didn't write this clearly: the _.jar_ file is only the games framework, with one main class inside, that calls other classes in the _.jar_ for visualization and upholding the games rules. I have no access to the source code of those classes. The two players, which I have programmed, are saved in a different package. And to run those two, I have to start the main class from the jar file with those two as arguments.

Comment: Okay, what's the expected argument format for the main class of the game framework? And what is its main class, so that I can adjust my answer accordingly? And what's the game framework jar called?

Comment: I've amended my answer to give you an example of how to do the Java call to your game framework. Without the correct argument format for your game framework, I can't say precisely. Please advise on this aspect, so I can update my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it via a (Windows) batch file, given a known list of classes that you wish to run from a single jar, with no dependencies...

```
@echo off
:: You'll need to edit this list with your ACTUAL fully qualified class names
:: from example.jar, or whatever your jar is called.
set classesToRun=package1.Class1;package2.Class2;package3.example.game.Class3

for %%c in (%classesToRun%) do (
    java -cp example.jar %%c
)

set classesToRun=
@echo on
```

As you can see, you don't have to specify a main-class attribute in your jar file. That's only if there's a single main class point of entry. Even if you do define one, then you don't have to call it. If you wanted to call the default main class, then you'd use the `-jar` parameter, but you **do not have to**, by any means.

If you have any dependencies, then you'll have to add them after the example.jar line above, delimited by a `;` i.e.

```
java -cp example.jar;dependency1.jar;dependency2.jar %%c
```

In your SPECIFIC example, it sounds like you are calling the game framework jar passing your own classes to it as parameters. I don't know the format that is expected in your game framework, but it may be something like this (you can advise me of the correct format and I'll amend the answer accordingly)...

```
java -cp GameFramework.jar;YourClasses.jar game.framework.MainClass path.to.YourClass1 path.to.YourClass2
```

You'll need to update the above to match your game framework jar and main class and substitute your own classes as parameters to that main class. I'm making the assumption at present that the game framework takes your classes as individual arguments at present, but you can either advise me or adapt this to suit the actual argument format of your game framework.